# C# EWS Managed API : How to get mailbox maximum size or quota limit

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to get maximum size of mailbox or quota limit. Actually I am find free space of mailbox. So I am finding used space and max space and then finding difference to find free space.

I got below code to find used size for folder. I think I can iterate to all folder to get full size. But how can I get maximum quota limit?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail", "pass");
            service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_Extended_Message_Size = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3592, MapiPropertyType.Long);
            PropertySet psPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { PR_Extended_Message_Size };
            Folder Inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, psPropertySet);
            long FolderSize = 0;
            if (Inbox.TryGetProperty(PR_Extended_Message_Size, out FolderSize))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(FolderSize/1024);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be able to query them just like you query the extended_message_size. find the MAPI property constants for the quota here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/outlooking/2013/09/19/mailbox-quota-in-outlook-2010-general-information-and-troubleshooting-tips/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code you have, just instead of `PR_Extended_Message_Size`, query for `PR_Prohibit_Receive_Quota` (hex value 0x666A0003), which is, according to [documentation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/outlooking/2013/09/19/mailbox-quota-in-outlook-2010-general-information-and-troubleshooting-tips/), "The limit where receiving mail is prohibited (also the maximum size of the mailbox)".

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. What I did was replace 3592 with 0x666A https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203094(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: But I think I am doing it wrong. I am trying to get that property on folder only? I want to get that property on mailbox. How can I do that? can you help with that.